# What should i use prefetch or next?

Tags: html, firefox, prefetch

As some of you may know, FireFox has the option to [prefetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Link_prefetching_FAQ) webpages.

Now from the docs :

```
<link rel="prefetch alternate stylesheet" href="mozspecific.css">
<link rel="next" href="2.html">
```

Now from what i understand, anything you prefetch will be prefetched, however when should i use the prefetch rel and when to use the next?

Meaning how will all my links look like when trying to prefetch multipile resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rel="prefetch"` is for things (styles, scripts, images) that the current page is likely to require soon and that are better be cached already. `rel="next"` is for web pages that the user is likely to navigate next. It's as simple as that.

From [HTML5 standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/):

> The `prefetch` keyword indicates that preemptively fetching and
>   caching the specified resource is likely to be beneficial, as it is
>   highly likely that the user will require this resource.

And a bit below:

> The `next` keyword indicates that the document is part of a sequence,
>   and that the link is leading to the document that is the next logical
>   document in the sequence.

So `rel="next"` doesn't inherently indicate that this web page needs to be prefetched - Firefox might choose to do it however because the user will likely navigate to it next (not sure whether it is currently happening).

Comment: It's far from what i understood from the docs, could u qoute or link to the resource u based your answer on? because prefetch is **not** for current page for sure, according to docs.

Comment: @eric.itzhak: As you wish - the documentation already links to the relevant document however.